# Capture and store video of few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to capture video streaming and got to work out the below (From this blog https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera)

HTML code

```
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

JS code

```
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    });
}
```

Snapping a photo I can do from here (which anyways I am doing using `Jquery-Webcam` plugin).

Question: Following the above technique, How can I capture a video stream of say 50seconds? and save that to disk?

I know there are third party API (commercial) present for this stuff like [OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/dot-net/) but keeping those as last resort.

Any idea? Please share. Also no shy but my JavaScript skill is pretty beginner level, so a little code snippet example would be really appreciated and if not; pointing to documentation from where I could work stuff out; would also be great.

Comment: maybe this could help https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

Comment: @jakob, Hmm, coincidence ... already going through it while posted the question.